# Uber sandbox-API returns 429

Tags: uber-api

I am unable to hit Uber Sandbox-API . It is returning 429 Error and its rate limit. I have experimented some scenarios  need to demo to my Leadership team . Budget allocation will be done based on this . Can you increase the limit now and is there any contact person i can talk

Answer (score 2):

Per our direct discussion, Uber believes there is potentially a background process your app is running that is causing the rate limits. From our traffic logs we see your app being correctly rate limited even after we have increased the limits. Let's continue your specific discussion on that direct thread. If we discover anything that is generally applicable or something that would be helpful for this wider audience, I will add it to this thread.

Thanks, 
Kyle